# After cell updates the database, the UI blocks; how can I fix?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, cocoa-touch, grand-central-dispatch

I have a `UITableViewCell` with a custom delegate method, `didJoinGroupConvo`. I'm making an update to Firestore and when I do, the UI blocks if I scroll while the update is in progress.

How can I fix this main thread blocking so the user has the smoothest (pun intended) experience?

```
func didJoinGroupConvo(groupConvoId: String) {
    guard !joinedGroupConvoIds.contains(groupConvoId) else { return }
    joinedGroupConvoIds.append(groupConvoId)

    guard
        let row = suggestedGroups.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == groupConvoId }),
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: row, section: 0)) as? GroupMessageSettingsUserCell,
        let currentUser = PFUser.current(),
        let currentUserId = currentUser.objectId,
        let currentUsername = currentUser.username
    else { return }

    // If I comment out starting here, it won't block. Otherwise, as long as it's doing this call, it will block the UI
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        Firestore.Collections.groupConvos.path
            .document(groupConvoId)
            .updateData([
                kMemberIds: FieldValue.arrayUnion([currentUserId]),
                kUpdatedAt: FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
            ]) { [weak self] error in
                guard let self = self else { return }

                if error == nil {
                    guard row < self.suggestedGroups.count else { return }
                    let groupConvo = self.suggestedGroups[row]

                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("Joined"), object: groupConvo)

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        cell.nameLabel?.text = "\(groupConvo.memberCount + 1) members"
                    }

                    let message = GroupMessage.createJoinLeftSystemMessage(joined: true, groupName: groupConvo.groupName, username: currentUsername)
                    message.saveMessage(to: groupConvo, withMessageType: .system) { _ in
                        self.delegate?.didJoinGroup(withGroupId: groupConvoId)
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm unable to scroll the UI or if I can, it's incredibly choppy and a bad user experience

Comment: I see nothing obvious here that should block your UI. By the way, I believe that the FireStore methods are already asynchronous and its completion handlers already run on the main thread (look at `Thread.isMainThread` or add `dispatchPrecondition(condition: .onQueue(.main))` to confirm), so (a) you might not need to dispatch this to global queue, though I might not suggest tackling that right now; (b) make sure you’re not doing anything computationally intensive in this completion handler; and (c) you don’t need to dispatch back to the main thread.

Comment: But I might suggest watching WWDC 2012 video [Building Concurrent User Interfaces on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012/211/) for illustration of how to use Time Profiler in Instruments to find what the source of the problem is. The video is dated, but the techniques presented here still apply.

Comment: One problem I do see, though, completely unrelated to your stuttering UI is that you are retrieving `cell` before performing the asynchronous request and updating the `nameLabel` inside the completion handler. You really should retrieve the `cell` just-in-time, inside the completion handler, in case the cell has scrolled out of view and has subsequently been used for a different row in the table by the time the asynchronously invoked completion handler is called. With the above code, if you scrolled quickly (assuming we solve that), you’ll see your label flicker as it's updated multiple times.